# List application available language

Tags: ios

I'm trying to print the list of languages supported by my app.

Let me explain a bit more : I have an app in two language (let's say english and french), and I'm looking for a way to print "en, fr" programmatically, so that if I added a third language, such as dutch, my function would then print "en, fr, nl"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [NSBundle's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) `localizations` method

The code should be as follows:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizations];
NSLog(@"Supported localizations : %@", array);
```